# Open email in Outlook 2013/2016 retrieved via Outlook REST API

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office365, office365api

I am trying to open a Outlook message in Outlook 2013/2016 that I have retrieved via the Outlook REST API.
How can I do this?

I have the weblink to open the email in the browser, but I have a requirement that the email should be opened in the users Outlook client on his desktop.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: No I didnt, I created my own simple email viewer to show the message

Answer (score 0):

Only the Outlook Object Model can be used to automate the Outlook application, via a VBA macro or a .NET application or COM Add-in.